# zabbix after the frontend install finished, the index.php report 502 bad gateway

Tags: php, apache, zabbix

Environment: ubuntu 14.04 and centos 7

Problem description: I have already finished the front end installation. And the click go ahead, the page report error and 502 bad gate way.

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me ???

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add some more details to your question. Maybe reading some of the [help documents](https://stackoverflow.com/help) helps you improving the question.

Comment: Please add more detail. Have you attempted to place nginx in front of the actual Zabbix frontend, for example?

Comment: Thank you. I have solved this problem.I didn't install nginx and config nginx. 502 error just results from the default port was restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by change apache2 port from 80 to 8001 and everything comes all right.

Comment: the 80 port is restricted by the VM.